# Error Using JUSBPMP : NetBeansProjects\JUsbPmP\libjpmp-0.1.1.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: java, usb, usb-drive

I am trying to access USB ports in java, so i tried using Jusbpmp.I tried testing it in windows I got the following error.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\T21034\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JUsbPmP\NetBeansProjects\JUsbPmP\libjpmp-0.1.1.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a IA 32-bit platform.**

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Jusbpmp project is made of two parts: a Java API and a native binary. The later needs to be built separately for every system architecture and operating system. The .so file extension distinctively marks this file as a Linux binary. As you mentioned that you are using it on a windows machine, you should try to use the jusbpmp.dll file found in the downloadable package. That one is compiled for 32 bit windows systems and so it should work for you.